# How to get the Current products grouping

Tags: sql, product, string-aggregation, historical-db

The objective is to get the the current product grouping after product modification date

[image]

Tried string aggregation + replacing word for each product...never worked.

Comment: Can you show your desired output for the given example? It isn't clear what is being asked. What is your existing SQL that doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I see now that the "After" is the desired output. Can you show some example data that you are trying to work with?

Comment: Hi Matthew, the current desire is column named After (needed).

Comment: But the transition is always from A+B to B+C. The way your example is written, the "removed" and "added" have no impact on the difference between the "Before" and "After"

Comment: A got removed, C got added, and B did not changed. A, B and C are completely 3 different products. It is not a count of product but a string of products

Comment: It would be useful if you could add some sample data to your question and potentially your existing code that isn't doing what you want it to. Maybe take a look at this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is the exact sample I showed beside the fact I renamed my products (A, B and C could be Land, Water and Air if you want....still be the same difference.,